# How to configure Maven installation and Maven Repository Location properly?

Tags: maven

I would like to know of Maven installation as I'm new on this. I dont know how but I already have a default installation of Maven on my laptop it may be installed at the same time when I installed InteliJ IDE.

However, I cannot decide what location is correct for my Maven Repository whether to change the default local repository which is: **"C:\Users[User-name].m2\repository"** to another Disk other than the default one, or it doesn't metter to keep project-files like "jars" in this?

Or maybe it is better to keep the Maven installation in the default location(**C:\Users[User-name].m2...**) and change the repository into different location for ex. in Disk D?

Any reply would be great!

Comment: What you mention `Maven installation` is the installation of the tool itself which is **NOT** located in `"C:\Users[User-name].m2\repository"`... This contains the cache of Maven. During the build all downloaded jar's of dependencies will be put there. So for the next build you don't need to download them another time. Apart from that I don't know if your local hard drive (c:) is a fast one because you wrote about an other disk?

Comment: @khmarbaise yeah, "C:\Users[User-name].m2\repository" is a repository location but Maven itself is almost in the same location, which is "C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2\apache-maven-3.6.3". What  I meant is is it better to create a different location for the repository than the current location, not in C: maybe in D:?

Comment: @khmarbaise according to some tutorials it is suggested to create another local repository other than the default one. This is what cunfuses me!

Comment: Ah now I understand your question related to the wrapper... you should keep it there... if you like to change the location of your local cache you can configure that within the `settings.xml` which must be located in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` see for details https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: yeah, I already know how to change. but based on some tutorials it is reccomended to change the local cache into different location other than disk C:. So, my question is does it really require to create a new local cache or it is better to keep as it is?

Comment: I would say if you local disc is ssd just fine ... if it is not and another drive yes I would change ... cause simply it's faster..otherwise just keep it...